# Excel VBA Using GetObject for Word Document causes Source Application May Be Busy Error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Alright, so I'm try to reference an open Word document. But no matter what I do it stalls out and causes an error. The error takes 20-30 seconds before it pops up

"The object is not responding because the source application may be busy"

```
Dim oWord As Object

Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Debug.Print oWord.Documents.Count
```

Just a simple code block like above when I try Documents.Count it errors out. So I can't do anything with the GetObject object. Anyone have any clue on how to solve this problem?

Thanks

I've tried everything I can find on the Internet. I can open the file using CreateObject, but once it is open I cannot access it.

**SOLVED**

I'm an idiot. So I went to the task manager and it turns out there were like 20 Word instances that were created through my testing processes, so the GetObject was just timing out. When I closed all the instances, then opened one instance and ran the GetObject it worked and Documents.Count gave the correct answer.

Sorry for wasting your time!!

Comment: I tried your code from Excel, using CreateObject - worked fine, did take quite a few seconds to open Word, showed 0 documents as expected

Comment: Yea, I can get createobject to work when no documents are open. The problem is when a word document is open I can't run any code. Not even Documents.Count

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine for me - provided Word is running - returning a result after about 1 second. What it lacks is code to start Word if it isn't already running, in which case it errors out.

What you need is something like:

```
Dim wdApp As Object, bStrt As Boolean
' Test whether Word is already running.
On Error Resume Next
bStrt = False ' Flag to record if we start Word, so we can close it later.
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
'Start Word if it isn't running
If wdApp Is Nothing Then
  Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  If wdApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Can't start Word.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  ' Record that we've started Word, so we can terminate it later.
  bStrt = True
End If
MsgBox wdApp.Documents.Count
```

Perhaps you should check in Task Manager for an orphaned Word session running in the background. Other than that, you may need to restart Windows. If the problem persists, you may need to repair your Office installation.